# Keycloak Bitnami TLS configuration

Tags: ssl, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

So I am trying to install Keycloak using the bitnami charts and I am trying to include private certificates to it as well , but it does not work .
I have spent a lot of time trying different ways but nothing is working.

In the logs I always see these warnings :

```
WFLYELY00023: KeyStore file '/opt/bitnami/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore' does not exist. Used blank.
ESC[0mESC[33m11:30:21,600 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.elytron] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYELY01084: KeyStore /opt/bitnami/keycloak/standalone/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self-signed certificate for host localhost
```

My ingress looks like this :

```
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    ingressClassName: "nginx"
    # -- Provide default path for the ingress record.
    hostname: localhost
    annotations:
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://localhost"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers-number: "20"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    tls: false
    selfSigned: false
    create: true
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - pods
        verbs:
          - get
          - list
    
    extraTls:
    - hosts:
      - localhost
      secretName: keycloak-tls-secret
```

I have created my own secret as you can see : keycloak-tls-secret

The default keystore path for keycloak using bitnami is :
/opt/bitnami/keycloak/standalone/configuration/

In the bitnami guides they mentioned to add :

```
selfSigned: false
```

I also tried to add in the yaml file :

```
auth:
  tls:
    autoGenerated: false
    enabled: true
    existingSecret: "keycloak-tls-secret"
```

I even tried to inject my keystore into the default path , here I got an error a file not presented called standalone-ha-default.xml

I did it this way

```
extraVolumes:
  - name: app-keystore-volume
    secret:
      secretName: keycloak-appkeystore-secret    
extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: app-keystore-volume
    mountPath: "/opt/bitnami/keycloak/standalone/configuration"
```

for this last try I got the error :

> cannot stat
> '/opt/bitnami/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha-default.xml':
> No such file or directory

Anyways I am so clueless regarding that , when I try to enter to keycloak it just does the Self sign certificate generation .

Any ideas how to make it work ?

Thanks in advance guys.